# Is there a way to DESELECT SIMILAR (i.e. Select Similar)?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools, select

It is incredibly helpful to be able to select things by their trait (i.e. Select Similar > Normals).

Is there a way to deselect geometry in the same way?

Using the image below as an example:

- I want to flip the red normals on the power button, but all of the geometry is connected so I can't use Connect Linked
- It would be helpful if I could simply drag a large select brush over the whole area and then de-select the normals facing in the other direction, leaving me with only the normals I want to flip

Is this possible?

[image]

Note: I know various ways to get the job done, but in particular I'm interested in knowing if this specific way is on the table, as it seems the most streamlined.

Comment: So if you are not interested in other possible ways to flip them because you know various ways (for example, `Shift`+`N` to _Recalculate Normals_ should work since they are all connected), but want to select them by their normal direction - then probably this is not the best object as example for that. Because the main face is (almost) perpendicular to the side face bordering the blue area, and if you had to use a great tolerance to select them, then blue faces will be selected, too... oh, but I thought of a way, I'll write an answer for that.

Comment: Thanks @GordonBrinkmann I actually didn't realize that Recalculate Normals would work this way, so that's helpful indeed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use the *Select Linked* tool. In *Edit Mode* make sure everything is deselected and you are in *Face Select* mode by pressing <kbd>3</kbd> or the button in the top menu (selecting vertices or edges would work too, but faces is the easiest way especially when you don't want to specifically select vertices/edges).

Then hold your mouse above a red face and press <kbd>L</kbd>. Now all faces that are connected to this one will be selected (even blue ones) because by default the selected is delimited by *Seam* and I assume for now you don't have any.

[image: select linked default]

But if you switch from *Seam* to *Normal* in the tool options at the bottom left of the viewport, then only the red ones are selected.

[image: select link normal]

If there are more red areas that have no connection to the first selected, just hover your mouse over them and press <kbd>L</kbd> again - no need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, the *Select Linked* tool automatically adds to the selection, it does not replace the previous.

Another way for several red "island" connected to a blue mesh would be, to use *Select Linked* on the blue area and then invert the selection afterwards with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

The checkbox *Deselect* in the options can do the following: let's say the complete mesh is selected. If you hold your mouse over a red area and press <kbd>L</kbd>, with *Normal* enabled and you check *Deselect*, then the (connected) red faces will be deselected from the selection. However, the *Deselect* has to be activated each time after pressing <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! This is a great solution, except in situations like mine where there are multiple areas where the normals are flipped, this will select all of the similar normals.  I know you can at that point just manually go over the areas with the select brush and deselect what you don't want, but I was just looking specifically for a way to 'de-select similar' in the same way you can 'select similar' (e.g. in cases where you have one giant mess of geometry that needs to be cleaned up, i.e. models from Turbosquid), which unfortunately seems there is no elegant way to do.

Comment: @GlenCandle I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. This method will only select connected flipped normals, not "all of the similar normals".

Comment: Right, but unless I'm confused (which is very likely!) if there are multiple flipped normals on the same geometry, all connected, then you'd be selecting more than just the one area in question

Comment: Maybe I'm confused or your example pic is not the best to illustrate the problem. You wrote in the question: _"I want to flip the red normals on the power button, but all of the geometry is connected so I can't use Connect Linked"_. To me this sounds as if you want to flip **all red** ones, but cannot select them with _Select Linked_ because they are connected to the rest of the **blue** geometry. If red ones that should be flipped are connected to other red ones that should not be flipped, I don't know how Blender should tell the difference between them to automatically select correctly.

Comment: @GlenCandle And by the way, if this is not clear by now, if you set the option to limit the selection to _Normal_, it will not select flipped red faces if there are blue ones between them and the red ones you select, even though the red faces might be connected via blue faces. Only direct connections from red to red are selected by _Select Linked_. That's why I explain under the second image, if there are more red areas, you have to select each of them separately if you want them all to be selected.

Comment: Sorry Gordon, it was me who was confused.  I get what you're saying now.  I need to train my brain to use code logic in order to really understand Blender, but it takes some getting used to as I've been a visuals only guy for twenty plus years.  Thank you greatly for your help ;)

Comment: @GlenCandle To me it actually seemed as if this was what you're asking for, that's why I got confused you accepted the "sorry, you can't do that answer" while I showed you that you can.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I have just changed that

Comment: @GlenCandle No problem, it's not about getting reputation for me, it's just that I want users looking for an answer to find a working one when it exists ;) Maybe I'll edit my answer later showing that you can select multiple "red islands" one by one with this method.

Comment: Gordon, not to get too sappy but... if it wasn't for benevolent souls like you I wouldn't have come a fraction as far with Blender as I have. Your contribution to this forum is greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately this is not possible. Select Similar operators do not have this functionality. You can only invert selection( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>I</kbd> ) once it's selected with those operators. I know it's not the same and  this does indeed seem like very useful functionality. I would normally recommend requesting this feature on [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/), but with [Geometry Nodes Tools](https://code.blender.org/2023/10/node-tools/) coming to [Blender 4.0](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/milestone/7) this is now irrelevant, because it will be possible to make tools like this(and a lot more) easily.

Comment: Thanks, it seems you are correct, but sadly I would not prefer to have to make a tool like this using geonodes, when it would be a lot easier to simply choose 'deselect' when using Select Similar.  Perhaps I will make a suggestion on Right-Click Select down the road ;)

Comment: Great news about Node Tools in 4.0, but it might be bad news in this case. Devs might be less motivated to work on this when it is going to become somewhat irrelevant with new release anyway... Even if someone starts working on it now, they are not adding new features to 4.0 it would have to be 4.1 even in the absolute best scenario. I think you have better chances of asking for help with nodes here(when 4.0 comes out only - questions about development versions are not really best thing on BSE) or on Blenderartists.org/devtalk forums maybe. More selection tools would be great for many people.